# Как перенаправить с неполного адреса на полный React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, create-react-app

Есть страница товара **`/product`** которая обязательно должна иметь 3 параметра после себя, то есть **`/product/1/1/1`**, нужно сделать так что бы со страницы **`/product/544/`** Перенаправило на **`/product/544/1/1`**

А со страницы **`/product/522/1`** перенаправило на **`/product/522/1/1`**.

То что второй и третий параметр это однёрки, так и надо.

Моя попытка:

```js
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/product/:product/:idType/:idSubType">
      <Product />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/product/:product/:idType">
      <Redirect to="/product/:product/:idType/1" />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/product/:product">
      <Redirect to='/product/:product/1/1' />
    </Route>
  </Switch>
```

Проблема моего кода в том, что используя редирект он не знает параметры `:product` или `:idType` и просто вставляет текст, при том что он должен вставить те параметры которые получил от родителя!

Я новичок в React буду очень благодарен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для обращения к ресурсу, чтобы попасть на необходимый компонент, который требует некоторые параметры в адресной строке, нужно в адресной строке передать значения для этих параметров. Если необходимо выполнять своего рода редиректы, то можной пойти через путь наименьшего сопротивления, ведь параметры маршрутов могут быть необязательными. О чем идет речь, покажу на примере, есть следующий маршрут:

```
<Route path="/product/:product/:idType/:idSubType">
  <Product />
</Route>
```

Здесь всё предельно ясно, при обращении к этому маршруту ему обязательно должны быть переданы значения для параметров `product`, `idType` и `idSubType`. Но вы можете отметить параметры как необязательные, указав в их определении знак вопроса, вот так:

```
<Route path="/product/:product/:idType?/:idSubType?">
  <Product />
</Route>
```

Такая форма записи маршрута означает, что значения для параметров `idType` и `idSubType` - необязательны. После этого следующие маршруты будут вести на одну и ту же страницу:

1. `/product/544`
2. `/product/544/1`
3. `/product/544/1/1`

И вовсе не обязательно использовать `Redirect` в вашем случае и описывать несколкьо `Route`. Достаточно описать всего лишь один `Route` с необязательными параметрами. А уже внутри самого компонента Вы можете определить дополнительные условия, позволяющие понять, какой из параметров указан, ну и переопределить значение, если нужно.

Ссылка на полезный источник: [React Router with optional path parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35604617/5275890)